# Displaying addresses using range-based loops in C++

Tags: c++, loops, auto

Why doesn't the range-based loop with `auto` display addresses?
The `for` loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < s; i++) cout << &ar[i] << endl;
```

works normally, but range-based loop with `auto` doesn't:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;
int main() {
    int ar[] = { 12,-23,0,1,2 };
    int s = sizeof(ar) / sizeof(int);
    int * m = &ar[0];
    sort(&ar[0], m+ s);
    for (auto m : ar)
        cout << m << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (auto m : ar)
        cout << &m << endl;
    cout << endl;
    for (int i = 0; i < s; i++)
        cout << &ar[i] << endl;
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: Because `auto` is deduced to `int` in this context? What did you think it is?

Comment: The explicit-loop equivalent is `... { auto m = ar[i]; cout << &m << ...`

Answer (score 7):

With the `auto m` you are passing (array) elements by value / copy in your range based loop:

```
for (auto m : ar) { // pass by value
    std::cout << &m << ' '; // prints addresses of copies, not the actual array elements
}
```

This means `m` becomes a copy of an array element in each iteration and has its own address in the memory.

If you passed by reference (`auto& m`) or a reference to const (`const auto& m`), you would observe the expected results:

```
for (auto& m : ar) { // pass by reference
    std::cout << &m << ' '; // prints addresses of the actual array elements
}
```

Now `m` **is** an actual array element and `&m` represents the array element address as expected.